# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotation $y=\ln x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> Calculate the volume $V(a,b)$ of a barrel that is created by rotating the graph of $y=\ln x$ around $x$-axis. The barrel starts from $x=a>0$ and ends at $x=b>a$. Also calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to 0^{+}} V(a,b)$.

So far I thought a good way is to calculate it by the disk method using the formula
$$\int_a^b π(f(x))^{2}\, dx = π\int_a^b (\ln x)^{2}\, dx.$$
Is my thinking correct and what about $\lim_{a\to 0^{+}} V(a,b)$?

Comment: What do mean by around $xx'$?

Comment: around the axis x.

Comment: Yes, your thinking is correct. To evaluate that integral, you can use integration by parts (you need to know the integral of $\ln x$). Get an expression in terms of $a$ and $b$ and then try to work out the limit.

Comment: Yes as for the limit, First you have to evaluate the integral before you'll be able to find out what happens. So the question is how will you try to integrate $\int^b_a[\ln (x)]^2dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ V = \pi \int_a^b (f(x))^2 dx $$

Note $ y = f(x) = \ln(x) \Rightarrow  x = \exp(y) \Rightarrow  dx = \exp(y) dy $. Thus,

$$ V = \pi \int_{y=\ln a}^{\ln b} y^2 e^y dy $$

$$ V =  \pi [( y^2 -2y + 2 ) e^y ]_{y=\ln a}^{\ln b} $$

$$ V = \pi [ (\ln^2 b -2 \ln b + 2)b - (\ln^2 a - 2 \ln a + 2) a ]. $$

Limit: as $a \to 0+$, we have $(a\ln^n a) \to 0 $ for all $n \ge 1$. Thus,

$$  \lim_{a \to 0+} V = \pi b(\ln^2 b -2 \ln b + 2). $$